# Format a string that's printed to a PyQT5 QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I'm running a process, that prints text like this to a QTextEdit box:

> b'Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]\r\n\r\nOptions:\r\n  General Options:\r\n    -h, --help

I want to format the text, so it either removes the \n \r stuff, and the "b'" at the start of each line, or does the actual formatting like starting on a new line if there's "\n" there. The b' is there every time, so i use string[2:] to solve that.(removing the two first characters basically) But that doesn't take care of the other issue.

I'm not sure if QTextEdit can do this on it's own, or with a PyQT function, or if i need to import something else just to remove it. Unless there's a built in python function that can solve this that i don't know about.

For code, here's the creation of the textedit, as well as the function which appends the text to the box.

```
self.edit = QTextEdit()
self.edit.setReadOnly(True)
self.edit.setWindowTitle("QTextEdit Standard Output Redirection")
self.edit.append('Welcome!\n\nAdd video url, or load from text file.')
```

Append function:

```
self.edit.append(str(self.readAllStandardOutput())[2:])
```

Comment: `lines = self.readAllStandardOutput().data().decode()`.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro! That works! Just added the `.data().decode()` to the end of the readAll...() and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7771743/7388106) is a simple example where `append` function works as you wish. The function correctly formats newlines and all the other stuff (as can be seen by replacing the `spam spam...`string in `handleTest()` by your string).

However, I'm not really sure what the `b'` should actually do, therefore I advise to remove it (as you already do).